# Mouseover left-most 10px of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the color of a table cell when the mouse hovers over the left-most 10 pixels of the cell. Currently I have this:

```
$("#myTable table thead tr th:nth-child(3)").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
$("#myTable table thead tr th:nth-child(3)").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

This works for hovering over the whole element, but I need it to only happen when hovering over the left-most 10px of it.

Comment: Can you just add a div 10px wide to the left side of the cell and target that on the mouseover instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`mousemove`](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/BLqrF/2/) instead and check offset coordinates:

```js
$("div").on({
    mousemove: function (e) {        
        var $this = $(this);
        var x = e.offsetX;
        
        // fix for firefox
        if(typeof x === "undefined"){
           x = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;     
        }        
        
        $this.css("background-color", x <= 10 ? "red" : "white");
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test test test test</div>
```

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: jQuery doesn't seem to populate the `e.offset` properties in FireFox. I've posted a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Put a div 10px wide to the left side and target that for the mouseover:

**HTML**

```
<th>
  <div class="hover-target"></div>
  <p>Name</p>
</th>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
  $("#myTable thead tr .hover-target").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "red");
  });
  $("#myTable thead tr .hover-target").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "white");
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FDRm8/

Comment: Visual Studio gives me the warning: `Validation (HTML5): Element 'div' cannot be nested within element 'th'.`

Comment: Really? I'm not aware of a reason as to why it's not valid. Does it cite a source for the validation error?

Comment: Are you using an old version?  See:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762026/html5-validator-incorrectly-disallows-div-within-th